# Finding a trace dual basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Suppose $E$ be an extension of the finite field $F$ of degree $n$. Let $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$ be a basis of $E$ over $F$.

**If $a$ is given, how can we find the dual of  $a$?**

As far as I know, the dual basis $b=(b_1,...,b_n)$ of $a$ can be obtained as follows:

let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with $A[i,j]=Trace(a_i* a_j)$ then the coordinate vector of $b_i$ with respect to $a$ over $F$ is computed as $(b_{i1},...,b_{in})=A^{-1}\times I_j$ where $I_j$ is the $j$-th column of the identity matrix $I_{n\times n}$.
what is wrong with my idea?

Any tips for MAGMA implementation is appreciated.

Comment: Let's assume we have fixed a basis of $E$ over $F$ so that we can write $E = F^n$, so the dual space $E^*$ is also identified with $F^n$, and the pairing between $E$ and its dual is the dot product $(u, v) \mapsto u^T v$. Now the matrix $A$ whose columns are the $a_i$ satisfies $Ae_i = a_i$, and we want to find a set of dual vectors, i.e. a matrix $B$ such that $(Be_i, Ae_j) = e_i^T B^T A a_j = \delta_{i,j}$. Considering this identity for all $i, j$ pairs makes $B^T A$ the identity matrix, so you want $B = A^{-T}$, the inverse transpose.

Comment: thanks @Joppy, but here we need dual basis with respect to field trace not dot product.

Comment: Same idea applies: write down the matrix $X$ which gives the field trace $(u, v) \mapsto u^T X v$. Then by similar logic you need to find a matrix $B$ such that $B^T X = A$, yes?